# Javascript - Redirect after promise

Tags: javascript, redirect, promise

I am trying to implement the behavior of a server call with promises.

What I want to happen is, when the reply from the server is "success" I want to redirect to "success" page else if it is "failure" I want to redirect to "failure" page.

The current situation is that the response is not being waited for, and the browser is redirected **before** I get any response from the server, doesn't matter if it is success or fail.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve it?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
var ch_item;
Payment.postInvoice(dataObj, $rootScope.usertoken).then(function(res){
  if (res.message === "success") {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var payment_details = res.data;
      User.getUserById(res.data.stylist_uuid, res.data.customer_uuid).then(function (stylist) {
        ch_item = TC_Service.getChatCredentials(stylistInfo.uid, $rootScope.userId, $rootScope.usertoken, dataObj.request_uuid);
        openModelAlert("Thank you for your booking!");
        $location.path('/success');
      });
    }, 500);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function () {
      openModal("Sorry, please come back later.");
      $location.path('/failure');
    }, 500);
  }
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  $location.path('/default');
}, function () {
  console.log("Something went wrong with the payment, the response is: "+res.message);
});
```

Help me out guys :)

Thank you for your time..

V.

Comment: _"and the browser is redirected before I get any response from the server"_ Is redirect to `"/default"`? What is purpose of `$location.path('/default');`?

Comment: Your second callback makes use of the argument `res` but does not currently receive any arguments. You should actually add an argument called `err` to the second callback and use that instead of `res`. These are just names for the argument, so you could really use whatever you want. However, by convention, the `onRejected()` callback should take an argument called `err`.

Comment: Are you sure before any response ? If this is the problem then the promise is not working and this code has nothing to do with it. Also when you are using angular setTimeout wont be synced by angular you can try to use $timeout for this.

Comment: Hey @guest271314, the purpose of this line is to show that something unwanted happened. I was trying to understand the behavior while the code was running not as expected.

Comment: Is document redirected to `"/default"`?

Comment: Yes. Every time it is going to '/default'

Comment: It's not clear. Are there circumstances under which you do want to see the default page, or is it a complete red herring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning promises you don't need to put an if/else statement in to determine if the call has failed or succeeded. This is part of the default callback.

```
.then(
  function(response){
  //if success show the response in the log
     console.log(response)
  },function(error){
    //if error show the error message in the log
    console.log('Error: ' + error.statusText);
   }
);
```

As you can see from my example above. The first callback function handles the success and the second one handles the error. I hope you can work with that.

EDIT

Try amending your code to this:

```
var ch_item;

Payment.postInvoice(dataObj, $rootScope.usertoken).then(function(res){
      var payment_details = res.data;
      User.getUserById(res.data.stylist_uuid, res.data.customer_uuid).then(function (stylist) {
        ch_item = TC_Service.getChatCredentials(stylistInfo.uid, $rootScope.userId, $rootScope.usertoken, dataObj.request_uuid);
        openModelAlert("Thank you for your booking!");
        $location.path('/success');
      });
  }
}, 
function (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong with the payment, the response is: "+err.message);
      openModal("Sorry, please come back later.");
      $location.path('/failure');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As you can see I have used the default callback, and in the current flow it doesn't get into the failed section. It enters the 'if' clause and until it gets back with an answer i am already redirected to 'default' page and several seconds later I am getting the "Thank you for your booking!" popup.
It looks like it is a multi-threaded approach. 
I wanted to use promises so that I could control the flow.. But it doesn't work for me..

Comment: I think the reason that is happening is due to the fact that you have a timeout function of 500ms around your if/else statement. Therefore your code for the `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  $location.path('/default');` will continue to execute as it's not in a timeout function. By the time it has executed this code your timeout has probably finished and then it will start executing your if statement.

Comment: Either get rid of the timeout function, or put your `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  $location.path('/default');` inside the bottom of the timeout function. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually the way that worked for me in the end was with $q(function(resolve, reject){...})

I didn't really know how to work with it, but once someone gave me a lead on it, I managed to solve it..

Thanks.